# When I Drag and Drop one image over another, why does it disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm adding a drag event to multiple images, which allows them to be dragged from one block to another and back. The code is working perfectly fine, except one small glitch. Whenever I drag an image and drop it on top of any other image, it disappears. Can somebody please explain why that is happening, and how I can stop it from happening??
I'm including the code herewith. Here is also the jsfiddle for it -  https://jsfiddle.net/Ljmqyz1h/1/

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div {
            float: left;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        #div2 {
            margin-left: 50px;
        }
        img {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        function drag(event, id) {
            var img1 = document.getElementById(id);
            event.dataTransfer.setData("osaicon", img1.id);
            img1.style.opacity = 0;
        }
        function drop(event) {
            var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("osaicon");
            event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
        function show(id) {
            var img1 = document.getElementById(id);
            img1.style.opacity = 1;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <img id="logo" src="osahub-icon.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event, this.id)" ondragend="show(this.id)">
        <img id="blue" src="Red_ball.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event, this.id)" ondragend="show(this.id)">
        <img id="red" src="Blue_ball.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event, this.id)" ondragend="show(this.id)">
        <img id="button" src="button.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event, this.id)" ondragend="show(this.id)">
    </div>
    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're appending it as a child to the target element. So when you drop it over `img`, it goes inside an `img` tag. etc: `<img src='img1.jpg'><img src='img2.jpg'></img>`

Comment: So how can I resolve this?

Comment: Change your `drop` function to append to the parent of the `img` element?

Comment: How? Can you please share code, I'm new to all this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you just need to test if the target where the image will be dropped is not an image.

```
if ( event.target.nodeName !== "IMG" ) {
    event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljmqyz1h/3/